# Is there a way for Emacs to autocorrect R commands

Tags: emacs, r

I'm a relatively new user to R and Emacs and was wondering if Emacs could automatically correct any R commands that i've typed wrong. I know about the alt-/, but I was more thinking along the lines of if i type **read.tale**, it corrects it to **read.table**.

Also, I was using emacs the other day and whenever i typed read.table, it showed the usage options (that bit from the help file) in the bottom bit of the window-the minibuffer?. anyway, its not there now, and i don't know what i did to make it go away.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

Independently of emacs, you can examine your code with the `checkUsage` function in the `codetools` package. For example:

```
> foo <- function(data){
+   read.tale(data,file='temp.txt')
+ }
> checkUsage(foo)
<anonymous>: no visible global function definition for ´read.tale´
```

Also, you can emacs autocompletion functions (e.g. `hippie-expand` or `dabbrev-expand`) to fill in the rest of recently used function and variable names.

Answer (score 4):

If you aint married to emacs, you should give Komodo edit with sciviews-R / sciviews-K a try. 
So far it´s the best auto-completion coding I found for R. At least to me the configuration was much easier than emacs, particularly because of binding problems with my exotic (swiss) keyboard. [sciviews-R / Komodo](http://www.sciviews.org/SciViews-K/index.html)

EDIT: I realize this thread is still being read. So in meantinem I got to give it up for [RStudio](http://rstudio.org/). It has really become THE editor for everyday use for most people. Nice autocompletion, available on all major OS and a really nice context help. Plus some easy export of pdf graphics and much much more. On top R Studio is easy to install – no need to worry how to fire up R from the editor.